# Bigcommerce stencil suggested cart content

Tags: bigcommerce

I can't figure out how to show suggested products on the cart page of a Bigcommerce Stencil theme. I'm following the documentation, but it doesn't seem to be working. How do I do this correctly?

Currently, at the top of my `templates/pages/cart.html` file, I have the following front-matter:

```
---
suggested_products:
  limit: 10
---
```

Then, in the body of the same file, I am trying to print the suggested product data to see if it's working. [The docs](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/cart-resources#Suggested) mention 2 attributes that seem to be identical, so I'm trying both because I don't know which is correct or if there is a difference. Either way, neither is working:

```
{{json cart.suggested_products}}
{{json cart.suggestive_content}}
```

Both of the statements print nothing. There should be suggested data because I added a product to cart and the url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/cart.php?suggest=573b3237853f4
```

What is the correct way to retrieve this content?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a bug that you should see resolved within the next 48 hours. It is labeled under MERC-722. The Stencil documentation is also being revised.

Comment: Thanks! Has this been fixed?

Comment: I see this fix mentioned in the [release notes](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/release-notes), but I see no reference to it in the stencil-cli repo in Github, and I am still experiencing the issue even after updating stencil-cli to what I believe is the latest version: `1.3.4`. Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: It was related to how the core application was handling that feature rather than the stencil-cli. Are you still seeing the exact same behavior or is it behaving incorrectly in a new fashion?

Comment: I'm still seeing the exact same behavior that I originally posted in this question. Nothing has changed with my setup or the results I'm seeing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea why but right after I posted that, I reloaded my page, and the suggested products are now appearing. Looks like it's fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Although, the suggested products are defined as: "A list of suggested products based on the contents of the cart in the current session", but they only appear if you are viewing the cart immediately after adding a product (aka if ?suggest=) is in the url. Shouldn't these products appear at all times since they should only depend on what items are in the cart?

Comment: This is currently the expected behavior. I'll see if we can open a feature request to expand the functionality and revise documentation for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. No matter what value I put in the front-matter, I can't seem to get more than 8 suggested products. Is this intended functionality?

Comment: I am having issues displaying suggested products on the cart page. I have added the correct Front-Matter to my cart.html file, but my URL never appends the "?suggest=123123123" onto the end. Is there something else I need to do to enable the suggested cart content? I noticed the Blueprint setting is not available in the Stencil admin area, and I don't see anything in the config.json file either.